# Understand significance of theorem related to normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I found in an [online book](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/section-factor-groups.html#SQP) about abstract algebra the following theorem:

> The following theorem is fundamental to our understanding of normal subgroups.
>
> **Theorem 10.3.**  Let $G$ be a group and $N$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then the following statements are equivalent.
>
> 1. The subgroup $N$ is normal in $G$.
> 2. For all $g \in G\text{,}$ $gNg^{-1} \subset N\text{.}$
> 3. For all $g \in G\text{,}$ $gNg^{-1} = N\text{.}$

Since I'm learning right now about normal groups and factor groups, I wonder why the author says that the "theorem is fundamental to understanding normal subgroups."

I found the proofs rather complicated, because we first show that $gNg^{-1} \subset N$, then the other way round that $N \subset gNg^{-1}$ to conclude $gNg^{-1} = N$ for a subgroup $N$ that is normal in a group $G$.

Somehow I fail to understand why this is so fundamental, can someone explain it?

Comment: That complicated method of proving subset equality is actually the standard method: given a set $X$ and two subsets $A,B \subset X$, the equation $A=B$ holds if and only if $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $G \to G$, $h \to ghg^{-1}$ is important in group theory, and is known as *conjugation by $g$*. The significance of the theorem is in showing normal subgroups are exactly the subgroups of $G$ which are invariant under conjugation by any element $g \in G$.

Comment: Thanks I think I can see a bit more where this is going. Can you expand a bit on "normal subgroups are exactly the subgroups of $G$ which are invariant under conjugation by any element $g \in G$"?

Comment: Well, that's exactly what $gNg^{-1} = N$ means. If you conjugate $N$ by $g$, then you get $N$ again.

Comment: Is this known as "Conjugation criterion of normality."?